# Copy of file from one s3 location to another does not work after athena query boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-athena

I am using boto3 to query results from athena. They are working fine.
I am using boto3 again to copy the file from one s3 bucket to another, but it says it is unable to find the file. I am unable to find a solution. Please help!

When I go to s3 console, I am able to see the file, but boto3 is unable to find it.

```
import boto3

athena = boto3.client('athena')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket1'
bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)


query = 'SELECT * FROM "db"."table" limit 2'
response = athena.start_query_execution(QueryString=query, QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': 'db'
            }, ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://bucket1/',
            })

key = response['QueryExecutionId'] + '.csv'

copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'bucket1',
    'Key': key
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'bucket2', 'main.csv')
```

Error is:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tanmaysinghal/Vizualization/Python Scripts/test.py", line 23, in <module>
    s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'bucket2', 'main.csv')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 379, in copy
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 106, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 265, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 255, in _main
    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer/copies.py", line 110, in _submit
    **head_object_request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is fundamental problem with your code, i.e. you are trying to copy the `Athena` `S3` `output` file before query was completed.
When you see it in console, it takes some seconds for you to see and by that time the file is ready. 
You must wait for `Athena` to complete your query and write the `output` to `S3`.

Here is how Athena works:

1. Submit a query.
2. Check the `status` of your query.
3. If status is `running`, wait and go to step 2. Elseif `SUCCEEDED`, go to step 4. Else FAILED, then do the corrective action.
4. read the output `S3 file`.

Here goes the working code.

```
import boto3
import time
athena = boto3.client('athena')
# s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
# BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket1'
# bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

query = 'SELECT *  FROM your-database.your-table  limit 10'
response = athena.start_query_execution(QueryString=query, QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': 'your-database'
            }, ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://your-s3-output-bucket',
            })

execution_id = response['QueryExecutionId']

key = execution_id + ".csv"
state = 'RUNNING';
##waiting for query to complete and then read the result.
while (state in ['RUNNING']):
    response = athena.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=execution_id)
    if 'QueryExecution' in response and \
                'Status' in response['QueryExecution'] and \
                'State' in response['QueryExecution']['Status']:
            state = response['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']
            if state == 'FAILED':
                print("FAILED")
            elif state == 'SUCCEEDED':
                s3_path = response['QueryExecution']['ResultConfiguration']['OutputLocation']
                print("S3-Path:" + s3_path)
    time.sleep(1)

# If state is succeeded, meaning query has completed successfully, now, you could read the output file or try copy it to somewhere else.
if state == 'SUCCEEDED':
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': 'your-s3-output-bucket',
        'Key': key
    }
    s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'bucket2', 'main.csv')
```

Hope it will help you!